# I want to copy all ".proto" files from one directory to another directory when i perform 'Build>Clean solution']

Tags: c#, visual-studio, proto, csharpcodeprovider, proto3

I am working with .proto files(Proto3) and I want to copy all the .proto files from one directory(Outside project) to another directory(Inside VS project) when i perform Build>Clean solution.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to modify "Visual C# Project file (.csproj)" file but no success

I want all the .proto files to be copied to a folder which is inside project.

Comment: you may have to use `Pre-build event command line`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JohnB. I am new to visual studio. Can you please provide me any link which can be helpful !

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019